# Move application from Apps to Background Processes in Task Manager

Tags: c#, winforms, trayicon

I've made simple WinForms application, single purpose of which is showing popup messages. Basically, it is minimized form with hidden taskbar icon, and NotifyIcon.

Everything works ok, but I don't like it being placed in Apps category in Task Manager, not Background Processes. So, what is a difference between background process and app in terms of VS project settings, class usages etc?

Comment: Have you tried `TopLevel = false` on your main form?

Comment: @BenVoigt well, that was simple. Thanks for reply. Could you add this as answer, so i could select it as right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task manager detection of "Applications" depends on the process having a top-level window.

You can avoid this, and be detected as a "Background Process" by not having a top-level window.  Since notification icons need a window, you can't get rid of it entirely, but you can set `TopLevel = false`.

This will probably also remove it from the taskbar.